# Xcode Weather app

Tags: xcode, api, google-api, weather

I want to try to make a weather app... but how do i get the weather info and use them in my app?

I heard about Google IPA  but how to use it?

Comment: You might find it useful https://github.com/hadanischal/WeatherRxSwift ,  https://github.com/hadanischal/WeatherRxSwift

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First pick the best weather API for your purpose:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis

Most APIs, including Google, return their result in XML format.
Quickly written example code to get you started with the Google Weather API:

```
NSString * location =  @"Amsterdam";
NSString * address = @"http://www.google.co.uk/ig/api?weather=";
NSString * request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",address,location];
NSURL * URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];
NSError * error;    
NSString* XML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

// Extract current temperature the 'dirty' way
NSString * temp = [[[[XML componentsSeparatedByString:@"temp_c data=\""] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"It's currently %@ degree in %@.", temp, location);

// Parse the XML with NSXMLDocument to extract the data properly
NSXMLDocument * doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:XML options:0 error:NULL];
```

Output:

> It's currently 14 degree in Amsterdam.

Comment: NICE:) but... can i just change the location "Amsterdam"?                  e.g. insted of                                                  NSString * location =  @"Amsterdam"                                        then                                                               NSString * location =  @"Copenhagen" or                               NSString * location =  @"London"????

Comment: Yes, simply change the `location` to request the information for another city or country. If the request is invalid, Goolge returns something like this within the XML: `<problem_cause data=""/>`. Note: Implement `NSXMLDocument` to extract all data and handle errors properly.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, when I run the app it saids "It's currently (null) degree in Amsterdam." Please help :(

Comment: There is an error on "NSXMLDocument" so I used "NSXMLParser" instead, is this why I am getting this problem? I really need this :(

Comment: This is because Google shut down its Weather service

Answer (score 0):

I created sample **iOS Weather app** using- Swift,Protocaol oriented programming(POP), Codable, OpenWeatherMap Api, MVVM design pattern with Unit Test.

https://github.com/deepakiosdev/WeatherApp/tree/master

May be it will helpful for someone who is looking all these things.